# How to re-write timthumb.php image url?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

Hi, I want to "compress" timthumb.php urls like:

```
http://mydomain.com/wp/themes/mymagazinetheme/timthumb.php?
src=http://mydomain.com/wp/media/sampleimage.jpg&h=400&w=580&zc=1
```

to:

```
http://mydomain.com/wp/media/sampleimage-400-580-1.jpg
```

Is it possible?, so please help me here is my thumb.php file.

Comment: Let me know why you want to do this. Why don't you use wordpress default image_resize functions

Comment: exact duplicate http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57322/how-to-short-url-in-timthumb-php

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of long, but maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^wp/media/([^\-/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ /wp/themes/mymagazinetheme/timthumb.php?src=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/wp/media/$1.$5&h=$2&w=$3&zc=$4 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: please have look at this http://www.dollarshower.com/timthumb-and-wordpress-blog-performance/ but i am very confuse

Comment: @Nisha_Behance Sorry, take a look at my edit, no idea why the answer was split into 2 lines.

Comment: mine is wp-content/themes/bdtheme/thumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Hindi2.jpg&w=100&h=100&zc=1&q=90 so 

RewriteRule ^wp/media/([^\-/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ /wp-content/themes/bdtheme/thumb.php?src=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/wp/media/$1.$5&h=$2&w=$3&zc=$4 [L,R=301]