# Internal server url redirecion

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx

Following [How to re-write timthumb.php image url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314717/how-to-re-write-timthumb-php-image-url) 
I was able to create the redirection in my nginx web server.

However, I would like to keep the original url.

So if a visitor get the url http://mydomain.com/thumb/120/120/image.jpg it won't redirect the browser to http://mydomain.com/timthumb.php/?s=image.jpg&h=120&w=120 but instead the image will be displayed under the same link.

Is this kind of (server internal) redirection possible?
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test it on my server, but it have to be more or less equal to such code in your site conf for nginx. Don't forget to restart nginx after changing config.

```
Location /thumb/ {
    rewrite ^/thumb/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)\..*$ /timthumb.php/?s=$3&h=$2&w=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: to make it work, I've to change my nginx conf file to:
    location ~* ^/thumb/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/thumb/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ /timthumb.php?src=http://$host/$3&zc=1&w=$1&h=$2 last;
    }
Anwyay... thank you very much for the tip! It saves my day... ;)